# How to select mysql row where idu is the same as SESSION id

Tags: php, mysql, session

So i am making a small website and want to select a mysql row where the idu in the row is the same as Session id of the user which is just logged into the site, the session works great on other pages of the site but i am helpless with this, see the codes below

```
<?php
include('solutions/session.php');
$id ='';
$id= $_SESSION['id'];
$page_name = 'settings';
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","usbw","company");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM payment WHERE idu='$id'");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['wallet'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['amount'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

and session.php looks like this

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "usbw");
$db         = mysql_select_db("company", $connection);
session_start();
$user_check    = $_SESSION['login_user'];
$ses_sql       = mysql_query("select username from wallet where username='$user_check'", $connection);
$row           = mysql_fetch_assoc($ses_sql);
$login_session = $row['username'];
if (!isset($login_session)) {
    header("location: index.php");
  mysql_close($connection);
}
?>
```

Comment: is `var_dump($_SESSION['id']);` show the correct user id ? are you sure $_SESSION['id'] is defined ?

Comment: it just shows `int(0)`, so i am pretty sure the session id isnt defined, but because i never worked with script like this and am a newbie in general coding i dont know how to define it here

Comment: You need to define your $_SESSION['id'] when your user login. probably at the same time you define your $_SESSION['login_user']

Answer (score 0):

First of all your **session.php** file code is not working because you are using mysql_query and also passing the connection that cause error use **mysqli_query()**

```
$ses_sql = mysqli_query($con,"select username from wallet where username='".$id."' ");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ses_sql);
//then set your session variable most imortant is id which is usefull
$_SESSION['id'] = $row["id"];
```

Rest of the things are good

Answer (score -1):

Try replacing this line:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM payment WHERE idu='$id'");
```

with this one:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM payment WHERE idu=".$id);
```

Comment: Still the same, no error and it just doesnt show any rows from the table, i still have the var_dump of session id on, and it shows this `array(2) { ["id"]=> int(0)`

Comment: Have you set the session variable anywhere like this: 
 $_SESSION['id']=$row['id'];

Comment: No, should i  have ?

Comment: Yes!!!That's the main part.That's what responsible for assigning the value of $id to $_SESSION['id'] .Write this code and I am damn sure that your code is going to work.